# how can I show user image with session in php?

Tags: php

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['sign_in'])) {
    if(!empty($_REQUEST['email']) && !empty($_REQUEST['password'])) {

        $sel = 'SELECT * FROM admin_login WHERE email="'.$_REQUEST["email"].'" AND password ="'.$_REQUEST["password"].'"';
        $result = $conn->query($sel);
        $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        session_start();
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $data['id'];
        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $data['firstname'];
        $_SESSION['user_email'] = $data['email'];
        $_SESSION['user_image'] = $data['image'];       

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1) {
            header( 'location:http://localhost/prit/Dynamic/glance_design_dashboard/web/index.php');
        } else {
            $msg = 'Please Enter valid Email Or Password';
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get image using with php ?

```
<span class="prfil-img"><img src="images/<?php $_SESSION['user_image'];?>" alt=""> </span>
```

Comment: die the $_SESSION['user_image'] and send the output

Comment: Is there anything not working with the given code?

Answer (score 0):

forgot to put echo in the HTML code

```
<span class="prfil-img"><img src="images/<?php echo $_SESSION['user_image'];?>" alt=""> </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
<span class="prfil-img"><img src="images/<?php echo $_SESSION['user_image'];?>" alt=""> </span>
```

or:

```
<span class="prfil-img"><img src="images/<?= $_SESSION['user_image'];?>" alt=""> </span>
```

Comment: can you explain to me meaning of this  <?=     ?>

Comment: Sorry for late answer.
<?= ?> will output whatever comes after =)
<?= "hello" ?> will output hello

Comment: <?=?> it is a short end, there you don't have to write echo it print by it self

Answer (score -1):

You should first get image name with print_r($_SESSION['user_image']); die; if you are not getting image name like stored in directory than you should upload and edit image name in database and directory. if you are getting image name and directory and found in directory than you should check the directory permission. Are you understand?

Comment: sdsdsa, this does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour)

Comment: @mozway Ok I've answered this question. can I remove? than how can I remove it?